# Troubles with constraints in my "Messaging app" code

Tags: swift, constraints

I'm trying to make an app. It's something like a messaging app, so i have the sender and the recipient. I have a collectionView as my main Controller, and i have a "ChatMessageCell" class, which is of type "UICollectionViewCell", and also i have a class of type NSObject: "Message". The problem is that when i implement all of these in my code, i get a lot of troubles with the constraints (specially when i try to send an image message).

The troubles are appearing when i first send a message like a blue bubble, and then i send another message like a gray bubble. It show me an error like this:

(This error example is when i send a message like a blue (nothing is wrong) and then i send another like a gray one (the error appears))

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000289790 UIView:0x7fbeead23880.width == 136.117   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000002896a0 UIView:0x7fbeead23880.right == practica_say_whaat.ChatMessageCell:0x7fbeead43770.right - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000002892e0 H:|-(8)-[UIView:0x7fbeead23880](LTR)   (active, names: '|':practica_say_whaat.ChatMessageCell:0x7fbeead43770 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000028b540 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' practica_say_whaat.ChatMessageCell:0x7fbeead43770.width == 375   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000289790 UIView:0x7fbeead23880.width == 136.117   (active)>
```

These are the constrains that are causing the error...
ChatMessageCell:

```
var bubbleWidthAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
var bubbleViewRightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
var bubbleViewLeftAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(bubbleView)
    addSubview(textView)


    //This is the bubble of the message (here is an error)
    bubbleViewRightAnchor = bubbleView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -8)
    bubbleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bubbleWidthAnchor = bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
    bubbleWidthAnchor?.isActive = true
    bubbleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    bubbleViewLeftAnchor = bubbleView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8)
```

HomeViewController:

```
var messages = [Message]()

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    cell.textView.text = message.text

    setupCell(cell, message: message)

    if let text = message.text {
        //a text message
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor?.constant = estimateFrameForText(text).width + 32
        cell.textView.isHidden = false
    } else if message.text == nil {
        //fall in here if its an image message
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor?.constant = 200
        cell.textView.isHidden = true
    }


    return cell
}

//In this function, i think is the other error connected to the other one)
fileprivate func setupCell(_ cell: ChatMessageCell, message: Message) {

    if message.id == 1 {
        //outgoing blue
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = ChatMessageCell.blueColor
        cell.textView.textColor = UIColor.white

        cell.bubbleViewRightAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.bubbleViewLeftAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = true

    } else if message.id == 2 {
        //incoming gray
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1.0)
        cell.textView.textColor = UIColor.black

        cell.bubbleViewRightAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.bubbleViewLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = true
    }

    else if message.id == 3 {
        cell.messageImageView.image = imagenSeleccionada
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that one layout constraint is making another one impossible. The only real solution is to go through the constraints and figure out which constraints are conflicting and why.

As a side note, if you only care about the end result and not the means then I would highly recommend looking at [JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController). It is an open source project that can save the headache of trying to do this manually.

Comment: I have updated the code and i specified the constrains that are giving me the error, can you help me to figure out how can i resolve the issue with those constrains??? Thank you!!!